# Dead Stack Overflow link

Tags: discussion, broken-link

Someone commented on one of my answers on Super User (https://superuser.com/questions/297103/how-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection/297221?noredirect=1#comment1807572_297221) informing that the following link is dead:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-add-on-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection-or-limit-bandwidth

I think it is crazy because the link existed on the past and now it is disintegrated. To prove I am not the crazy factor, another question ([How do I simulate a slow internet connection (Edge/3g) on a mac. Is there a Firefox plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596780/how-do-i-simulate-a-slow-internet-connection-edge-3g-on-a-mac-is-there-a-fire)) was pointed as exact duplicate of the same article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/473465/firefox-add-on-to-simulate-slow-internet-connection-or-limit-bandwidth).

If the article of the broken link still exists but in another link, please inform me which one. I searched for the text on link or the "473465", with no results.

If the article is really disintegrated, what do you recommend to do? Strikethrough or to use links to other articles?

Comment: The answer has been deleted which is why the link is now gone for anyone under 10k rep.

Comment: In the future you should quote the relevant parts of any page you link to in the answer itself. That way the important information is still there even when the link dies.

Comment: Just a note, that post has been deleted since September 2011

Comment: The history on that question is odd. Looks like it was migrated to Super User in 2011, the migration rejected in 2015, but yet showing deletion in 2011. It wasn't deleted by a moderator, community members, or the Community user, so I don't know what deleted it. Migrations can be weird.

Comment: Links on internet go bad... if that is surprising for you I'm not sure this is the right place to seek help. In mean time I'd recommend cleaning up question to either seek why answer was removed (which would be reasonable for SO meta) or how you should have created or edit the post on SU (which is not on-topic for SO meta).

Comment: @BradLarson It likely got deleted on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/330501/how-can-i-simulate-a-slow-connection-or-limit-the-bandwidth-that-firefox-can-us - Not 10k there, so cannot confirm. As for the late rejection date, I've no idea.

Comment: @Brad not really odd. The migration stub is auto deleted after a while (think it was 3 days in the past and 30 days now?), since it's done via process there's no user who actually delete, not even Community. So it shows the time the original question was deleted from SO. What happened to it afterwards is also not very uncommon, it was closed on the other site, and deleted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer has been deleted which is why the link is now gone for anyone under 10k rep on Stack Overflow. Here's a [screenshot for posterity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ql5C.png).

Your choices are:

1. Add enough information to your answer so you don't need to reference any external sites. This means that your post won't "break" again.
2. Find a better link. This will fix your answer but still means it might happen again.
3. Use the [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/) to find a cached version of the page. This is a bit of a last resort really.

Comment: Only a screenshot of the question is a bit, I dunno, too little? https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n6F5.jpg

Comment: @rene Well the screenshot was only meant to show the question had been deleted :)

Comment: I think I would earn 10k or more on Stack Exchange to migrate the question to Super User, hahaha. Do you (@DavidG and @rene) agree with it? For me it is a Super User question and it would be migrated to there, not closed...

Comment: based on the comment from @BradLarson it already came back from Super User. Let's not ping-pong a question between sites. And you only need 3K to migrate questons (assuming the target site is in the migration list). I asked a mod on SU to re-evaluate the question.

Comment: @kokbira I'm with Rene on this one, it's a deleted question, lets leave it that way. Most browsers have built in mechanisms to simulate slow connections so your answer is fairly useless now anyway.